# Quick Sort in JavaScript vs Ruby

Tags: javascript, ruby

I have a ruby background, and this week began teaching myself javascript. I've been doing practice problems to accomplish this.

If I were to solve this problem in ruby it'd looked like so (by the way when I coded this up it was a lot harder to switch off from javascript and code back in ruby....)

```
class Array

  def quicksort(&prc)
    return self if self.size <= 1

    prc ||= Proc.new { |x, y| x <=> y }

    pivot = self[0]
    left = self[1..-1].select { |x| prc.call(x, pivot)  == -1 || prc.call(x, pivot) == 0 }
    right = self[1..-1].select { |x| prc.call(x, pivot) == 1 }

    left.quicksort(&prc) + [pivot] + right.quicksort(&prc)
  end

end
```

Now I haven't had many issues with JavaScript....all the same concepts apply. Problems are solved the same way except syntax is different. I couldn't figure out how to write the comparator in JS, so I looked at the solution to gain some insight which is posted below.

```
Array.prototype.quickSort = function (comparator) {
  if (this.length <= 1) return this;

  if (typeof comparator !== "function") {
    comparator = (x, y) => {
      if (x === y) {
        return 0;
      } else if (x < y) {
        return -1;
      } else {
        return 1;
      }
    };
  }

  const pivot = this[0];
  const left = [];
  const right = [];

  for (let i = 1; i < this.length; i++) {
    if (comparator(this[i], pivot) === -1) {
      left.push(this[i]);
    } else {
      right.push(this[i]);
    }
  }

  return left.quickSort(comparator).
    concat([pivot]).
    concat(right.quickSort(comparator));
};
```

I understand the comparator is building out the spaceship operator in ruby <=>.

What I do not understand is what the if statement is doing, specifically what !== "function" is.

```
if (typeof comparator !== "function")
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated. JS is awesome and becoming my new favorite language!

Comment: `!==` is the negation of [strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Equality_comparisons_and_sameness). MDN for [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Comment: it's checking whether the passed `comparator` value is a function. If for example you call `[].quickSort()` then the `comparator` will be null, just like if you call `[].quicksort` in ruby `blk` will be nil.

Comment: @maxpleaner that totally makes sense. Why the quotes though around function? That threw me off.

Comment: Read the documentation that @ASDFGerte pointed you at: ["The **typeof** operator returns a string indicating the type of the unevaluated operand."](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).